# SQL too complicated nested query - can you make it simpler?

Tags: sql

I have built a hotel booking database in SQL Server. Three of the tables are below:

[E-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mQo1.jpg)

The relevant columns in those tables are:

- `Booking`: `BookingID` (PK), `CheckInDate`, `CheckoutDate`
- `RoomBooking`: `RoomBookingID` (PK), `FK_Booking_ID` (FK), `FK_RoomID` (FK)
- `Room`: `RoomID` (PK)

Now I wrote a SQL query (shown below) to try to figure out what rooms are free on a certain date (2017-10-02 to 2017-10-04). The code solves the problem but gets very complicated. I know how to solve this easier by having the `CheckInDate` and `CheckOutDate` in the table `RoomBooking`, but I want this set-up to work. Do you have any ideas how to make the code below simple?

BR/ Mike

```
SELECT FK_RoomID 
FROM RoomBooking
WHERE FK_RoomID IN 
      (SELECT FK_RoomID 
       FROM RoomBooking
       WHERE FK_BookingID NOT IN    
             (SELECT BookingID 
              FROM Booking
              WHERE CheckInDate <= '2017-10-04'
                AND CheckOutDatum > '2017-10-02')   
             )
         AND FK_RoomID NOT IN 
             (SELECT FK_RoomID 
              FROM RoomBooking
              WHERE FK_BookingID IN     
                    (SELECT FK_BookingID 
                     FROM RoomBooking
                     WHERE FK_RoomID IN     
                           (SELECT FK_RoomID  
                            FROM RoomBooking
                            WHERE FK_BookingID IN   
                                  (SELECT FK_BookingID 
                                   FROM RoomBooking
                                   WHERE FK_BookingID NOT IN 
                                         (SELECT BookingID 
                                          FROM Booking
                                          WHERE CheckInDate <= '2017-10-04'
                                            AND CheckOutDate > '2017-10-02')
                                         )
                                   )
                            )
                        AND FK_BookingID NOT IN 
                            (SELECT FK_BookingID 
                             FROM RoomBooking
                             WHERE FK_BookingID NOT IN  
                                   (SELECT BookingID 
                                    FROM Booking
                                    WHERE CheckInDate <= '2017-10-04'
                                      AND CheckOutDate > '2017-10-02')
                                   )
                            );
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please, format query to simplify reading. Much more readable when no need to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect a query like this:

```
select r.*
from room r
where not exists (select 1
                  from roombooking rb join
                       booking b
                       on b.bookingid = r.bookingid
                  where r.roomid = rb.roomid and
                        '2017-10-02' < b.CheckOutDate and
                        '2017-10-04' >= b.CheckInDate
                 );
```

This assumes that a room is available for check in on the day that someone checks out.

I don't understand why you prefix some columns with `fk_`.  The foreign key relationship should be obvious from the keys having the same names (and from being explicitly declared).  Many databases support the ANSI standard `USING` clause, and having different key names prevents you from using it.

Comment: Wow fast answer thanks a lot! I'm very new with SQL so I didn't know about the USING clause. Thank you for telling me this!